# Angular2 and Symfony combined in the same application

Tags: symfony, angular, routes

this is my first question on stack overflow so please be kind!

I have designed a Symfony server based application with an almost complete backend interface. Using symfony router, i can login in the backend using a url (ex. www.domain.com/admin) and see backend pages.

Based on this backend, i want to create an Angular2 application for dealing with the front end. It is quite straight forward to make it working for the front page url (www.domain.com). However, if i use any subroutes which would otherwise work in an Angular2 app (ex. www.domain.com/inner-page), Symfony router takes over and throws a 404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException.

The question is, how can i use both routers in "parallel"? Any URL under www.domain.com/admin will be handled by Symfony router, and any other url by Angular2 router?

**EDIT**

Thank you for your replies!

I have something in mind. It might not be elegant, since it will require manual exclusion of angular routes from symfony, and vice versa, but it will look cleaner. I am still working on it though, so its still a theoretical concept:

- For each url containing "/admin/", **Symfony** router will serve backend twig-php pages as it is designed to do. For any other url however, a simple controller will just serve the angular app.
- On the other hand, in the front end, **Angular** router will work as it would normally do. However, if a url contains "/admin/", it will be handled by an Angular component that will simply change window.location.href within its OnInit function to redirect to Symfony backend.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question a bit so we know what's happening. Post the minimum amount of code required to produce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angular app should be built separately, Symfony is a back end framework and isn't a good choice to use for building angular apps.

I created an example of how to use the 2 together, with FOS User Bundle and FOS OAuth Server Bundle to deal with authentication.

It's a couple of years old now, but should give you a good idea of how to go about using them together.

Github is down right now, but I'll update this with a link when it comes back.

edit:
https://github.com/mbates/Symfony2-AngularJs

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I indeed built them seperately, but at some point i have to combine them since i want both front and backend to be hosted on the same server. In the case of a single route (www.domain.com), this is possible by placing angular/html files in the correct locations of the symfony project (web & views dirs). However, angular subroutes won't work this way because the symfony router has priority and throws the aforementioned errors.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to setup. Why would the symfony site and the angular site be on the same url? It would be easier to have different subdomains for them, so nginx / apache can handle which of them is used. I think you're making things harder then they need to be by trying to put them together as you'll have to configure symfony routes and firewalls to exclude a specific route (the angular page)

Comment: Probably you are right, i am over-complicating things.. In any case, thank you for your replies!

Answer (score 0):

There is [AngularUI routing](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/) framework available in AngularJS for routing purposes in your AngularJS application. You can use Angular UI-Routing framework to govern your application's frontend while Symfony2 take care of the backend of your application. Angular JS UI-Routing URL's will looks like this,

```
www.domain.com/#page1
```

instead of this,

```
www.domain.com/page1
```

After the hash (#) the url will not be a part of Symfony2. The place where you map Symfony2 urls with Angular UI-Router urls will be within states. Take a look at this [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router). I hope AngularUI will solve your issue :)

Cheers!